# When select cell to pass data always shows nil in the next ViewController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to pass data when select or press cell in TableView, it's working and I can print the result while select that cell.
The problem when the second view shows the data is nil.

her is the code when when select cell:

```
var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectedPlayer : UsersModel = UsersModel()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
        return feedItems.count
        
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
        let myCell: WinnerTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! WinnerTableCell
        // Get the location to be shown
        let item: UsersModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! UsersModel
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.lbTextName!.text = item.name
        myCell.lbScore!.text = item.score
        let imageURL = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/image-upload/img/\(item.userImage ?? "nil")")
        myCell.userImage.sd_setImage(with: imageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "nullImageQuestion.png"))
        
        
        return myCell
    
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedPlayer = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! UsersModel
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayersDetails") as! PlayersDetails
    nextViewController.name = selectedPlayer.name ?? "nil"
    print("Print When select cell \(selectedPlayer.name ?? "nil")")
        
}
```

And her is the code in the second view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lbName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
var name =  ""

var selectedUser : UsersModel?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  
    lbName.text = selectedUser?.name
    print("Print when second view open via viewdidload \(selectedUser?.name ?? "nil")")
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I tried to print from the second view but it shows nothing. What mistake I did?

This is what i have out when print:

[image]
There is something I can not understand when I print, it start with the secondview?

Note: I am not using Navigation Controller.

Thanks

Comment: You create a new object `nextViewController`, but you don't show it. it's lost after `didSelectRowAt` method. I guess you used a segue, and that's why it's showing, but that's another instance. Put the "pass data" code in `prepareForSegue` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two** serious issues:

1. The main issue is that you assign the name to the `name` property but you are assigning `selectedUser?.name` to the label in the destination controller which is of course `nil`
2. The second issue has already been fixed by Taimoor: You have to present or push the controller.

So replace `didSelect` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedPlayer = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! UsersModel
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayersDetails") as! PlayersDetails
    nextViewController.selectedUser = selectedPlayer         
    self.present(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

And please **never use `NSArray` in Swift**. Declare the data source array

```
var feedItems = [UsersModel]() // why not just `User`?
```

and delete all unnecessary type casts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **pushViewController** to take the data to next screen. Just add one more line in **didSelectRowAt** function as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedPlayer = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! UsersModel
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayersDetails") as! PlayersDetails
    nextViewController.name = selectedPlayer.name ?? "nil"
    print("Selcted \(selectedPlayer.name ?? "nil")") 
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)           
}
```

This will take your data to next screen.

Comment: Thanks, but still pass nil even i add that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to execute "nextViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()"

Because you just created this ViewController, but did not present it, according to your hierarchical relationship, choose to use prensent or push to present it, it will execute "ViewDidload()"

Answer (score 0):

you've given feedItems's array type NSArray() instead to

> var feedItems: UsersModel = [ ]

or you assign name to selectedUser?.name of next page so that assign nil value
or that probably wrong

you have to implement at `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
       let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayersDetails") as! PlayersDetails
       nextViewController.name = feedItems[indexPath.row].name as! UsersModel
       print("Selcted \(selectedPlayer.name ?? "nil")") 
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```